# Matlab xlsread function

Tags: matlab, xlsx

I have 'data.xlsx' file with cells of numbers and letters.

when I run this command:

```
 [num,txt,raw] = xlsread('data.xlsx');
```

I got:

```
num =

NaN   NaN   NaN  
NaN   NaN     6  
NaN   NaN   NaN  
  4   NaN   NaN  

txt = 

'a'    'd'    'g'
'b'    'e'    '' 
'c'    'f'    'h'
''     ''      ''
```

there is a way to get a new variable which will contain both? something like:

raw =

```
'a'    'd'    'g'
'b'    'e'    '6' 
'c'    'f'    'h'
'4'     ''      ''
```

maybe by using num2str?

**I solved my problem, thanks all**

in yuk's solution, I got:
[image]

p.s. my version is Matlab 2010a.

Comment: you realize that new_variable in your question has the same contents as raw?

Comment: @bdecaf, yes, you are right, I meaned the same variable (I updated my topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[~,~,raw] = xlsread('data.xlsx');
%# find numbers
containsNumbers = cellfun(@isnumeric,raw);
%# convert to string
raw(containsNumbers) = cellfun(@num2str,raw(containsNumbers),'UniformOutput',false);
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Alon's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11036215/163080) that will contain cells with `'NaN'` strings if those cells are empty in the input file.

Just add after `xlsread`:

```
containsNaNs = cellfun(@isnan,raw);
raw(containsNaNs) = {''};
```

Comment: thank you, but I got an error: ??? Error using ==> cellfun
Non-scalar in Uniform output, at index 1, output 1.
Set 'UniformOutput' to false.

I use what I suggest in my answer, thank you very much!

Comment: Did you put those lines just after `xlsread` call, but **before** your lines? Works perfectly for me.

Comment: I updated my topic with the error and what I got (thank you).